# R1C1 in openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to set conditional formatting in **openpyxl** to emulate highlighting duplicate values. With this simple code, I should be able to highlight consecutive duplicates (but not the first value in a duplicate sequence).

```
from pandas import *
data = DataFrame({'a':'a a a b b b c b c a f'.split()})
wb = ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
data.to_excel(wb)
ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

from openpyxl.style import Color, Fill
# Create fill
redFill = Fill()
redFill.start_color.index = 'FFEE1111'
redFill.end_color.index = 'FFEE1111'
redFill.fill_type = Fill.FILL_SOLID

ws.conditional_formatting.addCellIs("B1:B1048576", 'equal', "=R[1]C", True, wb.book, None, None, redFill)
wb.save()
```

However, when I open it in Excel I get an error related to conditional formatting, and the data is not highlighted as expected. **Is openpyxl able to handle R1C1 style referencing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to highlighting to find duplicates of sequential values, the formula you want is

```
=AND(B1<>"",B2=B1)
```

With a range starting from B2  (aka, B2:B1048576)

Note - this appears to be broken in the current 1.8.3 branch of openpyxl, but will be fixed shortly in the 1.9 branch.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.style import Color, Fill
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['B1'] = 1
ws['B2'] = 2
ws['B3'] = 3
ws['B4'] = 3
ws['B5'] = 7
ws['B6'] = 4
ws['B7'] = 7

# Create fill
redFill = Fill()
redFill.start_color.index = 'FFEE1111'
redFill.end_color.index = 'FFEE1111'
redFill.fill_type = Fill.FILL_SOLID

dxfId = ws.conditional_formatting.addDxfStyle(wb, None, None, redFill)
ws.conditional_formatting.addCustomRule('B2:B1048576',
   {'type': 'expression', 'dxfId': dxfId, 'formula': ['AND(B1<>"",B2=B1)']})
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

As a further reference:

- If you want to highlight all duplicates:

  COUNTIF(B:B,B1)>1
- If you want to highlight all duplicates except for the first occurence:

  COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2)>1
- If you to highlight sequential duplicates, except for the last one:

  COUNTIF(B1:B2,B2)>1

Regarding RC notation - while openpyxl doesn't support excel RC notation, conditional formatting will write the formula as provided. Unfortunately, excel enables R1C1 notation only superficially as a flag, and converts all the formulas back to their A1 equivalent when saving, meaning you'd need a function to convert all R1C1 functions to their A1 equivalents for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Openpyxl doesn't support Excel `RC` notation.

You could use `A1` notation instead which would mean that the equivalent formula is `=B2` (I think).

However, you should verify that it actually works in Excel first.

My feeling is that it won't. In general conditional formatting uses absolute cell references `$B$2` instead of relative cell references `B1`.

If it does work then convert your formula to `A1` notation and that should work in Openpyxl.

Comment: It doesn't. It highlights everything indiscriminately.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use R1C1 notation directly, and this answer would be a **terrible** way to format a range of cells, but OpenPyXL does allow you to use row and column numbers.

```
cell = ws.cell(r, c)
```

returns the worksheet cell at row `r` and column `c`, creating one if needed.  Unlike the old [xlrd/xlwt](https://github.com/python-excel) modules, row and column indices begin at 1, so you can read `r` and `c` directly off of a spreadsheet  using the R1C1 reference style.  For most purposes, you want to access `.value`, for example:

```
ws.cell(2, 3).value = 3
...
v = ws.cell(4, 5).value
```

It's not nearly as pretty as `ws['R2C3'] = 3` or `v = ws['R4C5']`, but it helps with simple tasks.